# Angular Ng-repeat setup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'm trying to use ng-repeat and ng-show to split up data into two columns

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="row" infinite-scroll="eventSearchService.getMoreEvents()">
<div ng-repeat="event in eventSearchService.events" ng-show="$odd">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="row" infinite-scroll="eventSearchService.getMoreEvents()">
<div ng-repeat="event in eventSearchService.events" ng-show="$odd">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

While it works because I'm splitting up the data odds and even. What is happening is the boxes in the left div are much bigger and thus creating a div repeat that extends much longer then the column on the right which has much smaller divs. Is there a way to restrict the amount of divs shown on the left side or show just certain number up {{events}} from my array?

Comment: Sorry, What you are trying to do is, with one ng-repeat you want to display both the columns based on some condition?

Comment: Yes one ng-repeat flowing data within two seperate col's, the two col's have different box sized giving it that masonry look and feel, does that make sense?

Comment: Based on what condition?

Comment: What do you mean? What is in the controller?

Comment: You're missing some closing `</div>` tags...

Comment: Fixed,, that was just an error when I copied it over

Answer (score 0):

angular `ng-repeat` has the [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter which will allow you to restrict the number of elements that are repeated.

for example:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row" infinite-scroll="eventSearchService.getMoreEvents()">
        <div ng-repeat="event in eventSearchService.events | limitTo : 8" ng-show="$odd">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would limit the returned element count to 8